# Google charts doean't render corerctly when gridlines option is added the hAxis

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm defining a Google Chart

```
let chart = new GoogleCharts.api.visualization.ScatterChart(this.chartWrapTarget)

let dataTable = new GoogleCharts.api.visualization.DataTable()
      dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'datetime', label: 'timestamp' })
      dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number',   label: `${option.text} (${option.getAttribute('data-unit')})` })
      dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string',   role: 'tooltip' })
```

Now, I need to customize the `hAxis` but no matter which values I use the axis is not properly updated.

```
let chartOptions = { chartArea: { width: '80%' },
                     legend: { position: 'bottom' },
                     pointSize: 2,
                     hAxis: { gridlines: { count: 4 } }
}
chart.draw(joinedData, chartOptions)
```

Here an example of chart without the `gridlines` option (which looks fine)

[image]

And here other with the the `gridlines` option (which doesn't look fine)
[image]

Am I misisng anything here?

Comment: does it work as you expect if you omit `hAxis: { gridlines: { count: 4 } }` ?

Comment: Yes, it does, I mean without providing any customization the chart seems ok.

Comment: can you try it again by just omitting the `hAxis`? reason I'm asking is because according to the documentation, `hAxis.gridlines` is only supported for a continuous axis.

Comment: As you can see above the first column is `dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'datetime', label: 'timestamp' })` which should make the axis a `continouos` one. Moreover, from my understanding, the distinction between continouos and not doesn't apply to `ScatterChart`.

Comment: You are right about the distinction not being mentioned but I thought it was worth a try just to make sure that it's the hAxis that's causing the problem and not the combination of all the settings. I would also try an odd number of horizontal gridlines

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? do you simply want 4 x-axis gridlines?

Comment: Not sure how many gridlines I will need. Thinking to start with 4 and see if I will need more. Thanks.